# How to validate request body on flask server as per OpenAPI yaml file

Tags: python-3.x, validation, flask, openapi

I am new to OpenAPI spec and would like to use OpenAPI spec configuration for Python Flask server side validation of request body parameters

We can specify some rule to request parameters in OpenAPI yaml file. is there any module in Flask which helps us to enforce these validation in the backend and raise 400 Bad request if any input parameter does not follow OpenAPI spec validations?

I have a simple OpenAPI yaml file:

```
openapi: '3.0.2'
info:
  title: Test Title
  version: '1.0'
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:345/
paths:
  /test:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              required:
                - "flag"
              properties:
                flag:
                  type: string
                  minLength: 6
                  maxLength: 20
                  pattern: "\d+"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
```

And I have a flask server

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from flask import request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test", methods=["POST"])
def read_flag():
    stri = request.json.get("flag")
    return jsonify({"flag": stri})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=345)
```

The flask server takes input variable "flag" from request body, and we have specified minLength, maxLength  and pattern in OpenAPI yaml spec.

If I want to enforce those checks, I need to manually add those checks in Flask script, however is there any plugin/python module which can automatically perform validation on request body based on it's OpenAPI yaml file?

e.g in above case, if value of flag variable in request body is less than 6 characters, then the response should automatically raise 400 bad request.

Is there any Python library/module which helps us to perform server side validation using openapi spec file?